# Obtengo un Notice: Array to string conversion

Tags: php

Hola buenas estoy intentado llevar a expresión lambda el siguiente script que tengo que repetirlo en varias parte de mi código.

```
<?php
$arrayCorreos = explode(";", $tipoCorreo['Para']);
foreach ($arrayCorreos as $correo) {
    echo $correo . "<br>";
}
?>
```

---

```
<?php
echo $correo = array_map(function($elemento){$elemento. "<br>"}, explode(";", $tipoCorreo['Para']));
?>
```

Al hacer `var_dump($elemento)` me sale el *string* que busco pero al hacer el *echo* me dice `Array to string conversion`, no me queda claro cómo podría hacer que me imprima el *string* que hay en `$elemento`.

Comment: ¿Tiene que ser necesariamente una función anónima (lambda)? Una función normal puedes llamarla la cantidad de veces que quieras en el código.

Comment: El mensaje que obtienes es por que la salida es aún un array entonces deberías iterarlo para acceder a cada elemento, yo considero que en lugar de *expresiones lambda*, tu duda debería estar enfocada en lo primero que menciono

Comment: Cuando tengas problemas prueba el array en sí: `var_dump($arrayCorreos);` y revisa su estructura. Puede que sea irregular en algunos casos. Si no encuentras el problema, pulsa en [edit] y muestra el `var_dump` del array completo.

Comment: no tiene que ser una expresión lambda, buscaba poder llamar a ese script, ya que lo usaré en varias parte de mi vista, opté por crear una clase y ponerla en una función, luego en mi vista llamarla asi <?php echo Utilidades::MostrarCorreo() ?>. Pensé que habría alguna forma de hacer lo que busco, de forma que me imprima $elemento con una expresión lambda.